# Ubuntu 20.04.02 - installer crahsed at "almost finished copying files..." (what else can I try)?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, memory-leak

**Summary**

I am trying to have a dualboot setup with windows 10. I can successfully boot into Live Ubuntu with the USB stick with persistent data. I can update drivers, etc, and start the installation. However, the installer always crashed at the same point during "almost finished copying files". I have been searching for and trying a lot of things (see below), however, the Syslog output at the time the installer crash is always the same and it is "BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 0000xxxx. Below a list of specs, some logs, and things I tried. Hope for some useful advice. Thanks!

**Some observations**

- After the crash, I can usually resume the session in Live, but it will often hang after some minutes; I checked with `htop` and could see that 3 of the CPU have reached 100%.
- The partitions are created; could see it in both windows and in the Live session.
- I installed with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to check what exactly is written at the moment of the crash, see below
- When changing the USB stick and or flashing method, the page fault address is the same:0000000000029d00. Only when changing the image to 18.04 then I can see the same error pattern but the page fault address is another one.

**PC Specs**

- Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B550-I GAMING
- CPU: Topology: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
- GPU: Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT710]
- RAM: 2 x 16G
- HD-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: SA2000M81000G size:931.51 GiB
- HD-2: /dev/sda type: USB vendor: nvOCZ model: VERTEX4 size: 119.24 GiB
- Monitor: LG HDR 4k

Windows 10 is installed and running in HD-1. Trying to install 20.04 to HD-2.

**What I have tried so far**

- Downloaded and flashed different Ubuntu images from ubuntu.com: Ubuntu 20.04, 18.04 (SHA256 checked and is ok).
- USB flashing:

  - Used Rufus and balena etcher for flashing the USB
  - with and without persistent data;
  - GPT;
  - ISO and DD mode both tried,
  - tried different cluster sizes; default but also smaller ones
  - tried flashing two different USB sticks (the error was the same)
- UEFI Bios settings:

  - secureboot, fastboot turned off (confirmed in windows);
  - hibernation in windows turned off
  - IOMMU turned off
  - checked in windows, storage is AHCI (not raid)
- Disk partitioning both tried in Windows and using Gparted

**(?)** GPU Nvidia GT710 drivers updated to the recommended one 460.32.03. After installation and reboot confirmed with `inxi -G`. However when `nvidia-smi` I cannot see in the lower part **no running processes found**, not sure whether this has anything to do with the crash?

**Boot & installation**

- Power on, F2 and choosing for a boot with SAFE GRAPHICS
- Installation:

  - Tried installation directly after booting into Live, and starting from within Live session
  - Standard installation, without updates and 3rd party modules
  - Tried both the options: install along with Windows and the manual one where I choose for / 50G, /home 50G, SWAP 6G.
- After filling in the timezone and user info, click start install, I see that partition activity is ongoing, but it will crash during **" almost finished copying files"**.

**Log at the moment of crash**

```
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078188] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 0000000000029d00
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078191] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078192] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078193] PGD 6e9599067 P4D 6e9599067 PUD 6bbbb1067 PMD 0 
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078195] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078197] CPU: 1 PID: 30099 Comm: install.py Tainted: P           O      5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078197] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX B550-I GAMING, BIOS 1004 08/13/2020
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078201] RIP: 0010:__add_to_page_cache_locked+0x1c7/0x380
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078203] Code: ff 83 e2 01 49 8b 14 24 49 0f 44 c4 48 c1 ea 36 48 8b 40 38 48 8b 3c d5 a0 1d 47 bc 48 85 c0 0f 84 3e 01 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 <48> 63 97 00 9d 02 00 4c 8b 84 d0 48 0b 00 00 49 3b 78 78 75 24 ba
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078203] RSP: 0018:ffff9c11d5f7fb98 EFLAGS: 00010086
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078204] RAX: ffff8ad3a5b4f000 RBX: ffff8ad337c4a058 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078205] RDX: 0000000000000010 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078205] RBP: ffff9c11d5f7fc08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078206] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 00000000000057bc R12: ffffe81ed4f67f40
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078206] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078207] FS:  00007fd7cf049740(0000) GS:ffff8ad47e840000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078208] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078208] CR2: 0000000000029d00 CR3: 00000007f822e000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078209] Call Trace:
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078212]  ? scan_shadow_nodes+0x30/0x30
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078213]  add_to_page_cache_lru+0x4d/0xd0
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078215]  pagecache_get_page+0x101/0x300
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078216]  grab_cache_page_write_begin+0x21/0x40
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078218]  ext4_da_write_begin+0x111/0x480
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078220]  generic_perform_write+0xc2/0x1c0
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078221]  ext4_buffered_write_iter+0x90/0x140
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078223]  ext4_file_write_iter+0x50/0x220
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078225]  new_sync_write+0x113/0x1a0
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078226]  vfs_write+0x1c5/0x200
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078228]  ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078229]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078231]  do_syscall_64+0x49/0xc0
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078232]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078234] RIP: 0033:0x7fd7cf3261e7
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078235] Code: 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb bb 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078235] RSP: 002b:00007ffda921b8d8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078236] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fd7cf0496c0 RCX: 00007fd7cf3261e7
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078237] RDX: 0000000000004000 RSI: 00000000020b3080 RDI: 0000000000000005
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078237] RBP: 0000000001392120 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078238] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000004000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078238] R13: 00007fd7cd0df240 R14: 00000000020b3080 R15: 0000000000000001
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078239] Modules linked in: ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos xfs jfs btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) zlua(PO) iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 edac_mce_amd iwlwifi cfg80211 kvm joydev input_leds snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore ccp k10temp mac_hid eeepc_wmi asus_wmi rapl sparse_keymap efi_pstore wmi_bmof sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 overlay nls_iso8859_1 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau mxm_wmi video i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core aesni_intel crypto_simd drm cryptd glue_helper igc nvme i2c_piix4 ahci xhci_pci
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078270]  nvme_core libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078274] CR2: 0000000000029d00
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.078275] ---[ end trace b33df169e01baa57 ]---
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205142] RIP: 0010:__add_to_page_cache_locked+0x1c7/0x380
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205143] Code: ff 83 e2 01 49 8b 14 24 49 0f 44 c4 48 c1 ea 36 48 8b 40 38 48 8b 3c d5 a0 1d 47 bc 48 85 c0 0f 84 3e 01 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 <48> 63 97 00 9d 02 00 4c 8b 84 d0 48 0b 00 00 49 3b 78 78 75 24 ba
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205144] RSP: 0018:ffff9c11d5f7fb98 EFLAGS: 00010086
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205144] RAX: ffff8ad3a5b4f000 RBX: ffff8ad337c4a058 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205145] RDX: 0000000000000010 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205145] RBP: ffff9c11d5f7fc08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205146] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 00000000000057bc R12: ffffe81ed4f67f40
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205146] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205147] FS:  00007fd7cf049740(0000) GS:ffff8ad47e840000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205148] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 19 09:39:17 ubuntu kernel: [  487.205148] CR2: 0000000000029d00 CR3: 00000007f822e000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
```

**Memtest86 results**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Page fault is often a memory issue.

Comment: Hi @David, I think so too. I couldn't find much cases reported with same symptons.. the only tip I saw was about to turn off IOMMU in the bios, which I tried, but it didn't change the outcome, or I didn't see anything changes in the log when crash.

Comment: Boot from the live DVD or USB and run the memsheck

Comment: @David ok, did a memcheck with memtest86, took more than 6 hours :S. And it says failed and test pass rate is 4/48 (8%). Result added below. Should this be some configuration that need to be done first? Strange is I have never experienced issues when using windows. It is a new PC, bought like 3 months ago but rarely used because the new GPU's were not on stock.

Comment: 3 months old take it back. Take a pic of the memtest results with phone so you have them to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from the live DVD or USB and run the memcheck. 3 months old take it back. Take a pic of the memtest results with phone so you have them to show.

Comment: After removal of the bad ram, the installation of Ubuntu went smoothly.

Comment: Great glad to hear.